# how to use logstash-generated fields in kibana?

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have some Logstash-generated fields which I can see in Kibana (in discovery mode). They are not present in the sidebar, though:

[image]

In the example above `who` is well present in the data but not on the list of fields on the left.

Is there a particular action to take in order to have them appearing? (either in Kibana, or upstream, during the indexing by elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kibana4 caches the field list.  Go to Settings -> Indexes, select your index, then click the yellow "reload field list" button.